# Why all my the clusters are plotted in the center?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have clustered my data and plotted it, But why it's plotted like this, why it shows all clusters like this, while if it makes the range of x and y smaller, they wouldn't have any overlapping and would be plotted separately. Should I use any scaling or anything? [image]

Here, is the code:

```
    db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=200, algorithm='ball_tree',   metric='haversine').fit(X)

    labels = db.labels_

    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

    unique_labels = set(labels)

    colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels)))

    for color, k in zip(colors, unique_labels):

    if k != -1:
        class_member_mask = (labels == k)
        xy = X[class_member_mask]
        area=np.pi * (10 * np.random.rand(len(xy[:, 0])))**2
        plt.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], s=area, c=color, alpha=0.5) 

    plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
```

And if I use X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X), the plot would be like below. But I dont want it to be scaled with var=1.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code that generated the data and plot

Comment: I've added the code, It reads spatial data from db...

Comment: Can't you just zoom then ? limiting the `xlim` and `ylim` of your plot ?

Comment: I don't think xlim and ylim work here. I need to plot for different data, so each time I should calculate them separately, not a neat solution.